# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function

Tags: r, data.table

I consistantly get this error:

```
 Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
 could not find function "aggregation.method"
```

Example:

```
#sample data
Date.Time<- seq(ISOdate(2000,1,1), by = "min" , length.out = 200)
rh <- as.data.table(cbind(Date.Time,rnorm(200),rnorm(200),rnorm(200)))
colnames(rh) <- c("Date.Time", "A", "B", "C")
rh$Date.time <- as.POSIXct( rh$Date.Time, origin = "1970-01-01" )

#Custom function
Custom.data.wrangle<-function(x, timeinterval, aggregation.method)
{
  require(data.table)

  x$Date.Time <- as.POSIXct(as.integer(as.numeric(x$Date.Time) / (60 * timeinterval)) * (60 * timeinterval),
                            origin = "1970-01-01" ,
                            tz = "GMT")# Rounddown POSIXct in a simple form.

  x<-melt(x, id= "Date.Time")

  x<-dcast(x, Date.Time~variable, fun.aggregate = aggregation.method, na.rm=TRUE)  #Restructure the table
  return(x)
}

rh<- Custom.data.wrangle(rh, 30, mean)
```

I've tried a combination of quotes, noquote,

```
fun.aggregate = get(aggregation.method)
```

all to no avail. Please save my sanity!

Comment: `dcast` and `melt` are not base R functions. Please include the names of any packages that you are using in the text of your question.

Comment: Your way of construction a data.table is extremely suboptimal. The vignettes clearly show how to do that in a much better way. Anyway, you should report this to the data.table bug tracker. It's clearly a scoping problem in `dcast.data.table`.

Comment: Hello Roland. The data.table is for a reproducable example only. I'm pushed for time and never create them from scratch like this, so i was unconcerned about succinct code. Thank you for your advice regarding the bug tracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is intended behavior or a bug, but the following seems to work:

```
f <- function(agg.fun) {
    dcast(
        DT, 
        time ~ variable, 
        fun.aggregate = eval(substitute(agg.fun)),
        #               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        na.rm = TRUE
    )
}

f(mean)
#     time    weight
#  1:    0  41.06000
#  2:    2  49.22000
#  3:    4  59.95918
#  4:    6  74.30612
#  5:    8  91.24490
#  6:   10 107.83673
#  7:   12 129.24490
#  8:   14 143.81250
#  9:   16 168.08511
# 10:   18 190.19149
# 11:   20 209.71739
# 12:   21 218.68889
```

---

```
library(data.table)
DT <- melt(
    setnames(
        as.data.table(ChickWeight),
        names(ChickWeight), tolower(names(ChickWeight))
    ),
    id = 2:4
)
```

Comment: At least, it doesn't appear to be documented.

Comment: Marked as answered - it works for me. I will read up on the eval() function. Many thanks!

Comment: You bet; just note that `eval` should be avoided in most cases if possible, and so I suspect this may be a bug / unintentional behavior in the `dcast.data.table` function. You may want to confirm by checking for a [discussion of this on the package repository](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20dcast), or filing a new issue there if it hasn't been addressed yet.

Comment: Thanks for the link nrussel. I've checked the board and it's there, number #1369.